# Generic class call function

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a wrapper for my API return wrapper class for my project.

these are my classes

```
class Wrapper<T> {

   let message = "Hello World"
   let wrapped = T.self
   public func getData() -> T.Type {
       return wrapped
   }
}

class Object {

   let number = 100
   public func getNumber() -> Int {
       return number
   }
}

class SecondObject {

   let name = "Second Object" 
   public func getName() -> String {
       return name
   }
}
```

What I want to achieve is, is there any way I can call the Object function like this

```
let example = Wrapper<Object>()
example.getData().getNumber() // <<-- This is not working
let secondExample = Wrapper<SecondObject>()
secondExample.getData().getName() // <<-- This is not working
```

The error in my playground is this

```
error: instance member 'getNumber' cannot be used on type 'Object'
```

If you notice the Wrapper class, there is message property which will be used for all my API return object model

So my goal is, I could simply call the Wrapper class together with my object model class and just call the function that is inside the object model class.

I am still learning about generic in swift. What am I missing here?

Comment: *This is not working* is not a helpful description

Comment: edited explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't set `wrapped` to anything useful. You ned to set it to an instance of `T`. So you can pass a `T`into the constructor

```
class Wrapper<T>
{
    let wrapped: T

    init(wrapped: T)
    {
        self.wrapped = wrapped
    }
}
```

Or you can have the class construct an instance of T, but if you want to do that, you need to tell it how to construct the instance. For example:

```
class Wrapper<T>
{
    let wrapped: T

    init()
    {
        self.wrapped = T() // << error!
    }
}
```

won't work because the compiler knows nothing about `T`, not even if it has an `init`. You can change that with a protocol

```
protocol Initable 
{
    init()
}

class Wrapper<T: Initable>
{
    let wrapped: T

    init()
    {
        self.wrapped = T() 
    }
}
```

And you can apply the protocol to any type you like with an extension. In most cases the extension can be empty because mot types already have an `init()` method. For example:

```
class MyClass
{
    init() { /* do stuff */ }
}

extension MyClass: Initable {}

class MyOtherClass
{
    init(number: Int) { /* do stuff */ }
}

extension MyOtherClass: Initable 
{
    init() { self.init(number: 0) }
}
```

Another option is to supply a closure to the wrapper's init.

```
class Wrapper<T>
{
    let wrapped: T

    init(factory: ()-> T)
    {
        self.wrapped = factory()
    }
}

let w = Wrapper() { return Array<Int>() }
```

Normally you'd only do this if you wanted to create multiple instances i.e. you'd keep a reference to the closure and call it each time you needed a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Wrapper<T> {

    private var wrapped: T // Storing your object of T type

    init(value: T) { // init with instance of T
        wrapped = value
    }

    public func getData() -> T { //returning instance of T
        return wrapped
    }
}

class Object {

    let number = 100
    public func getNumber() -> Int {
        return number
    }
}

let o = Object()
let example = Wrapper(value: o) // Here we creating instance of Wrapper with instance of Object
example.getData().getNumber()
```

Comment: Sir, is there any other method without instantiating the Object first? Because if I need to instantiate new object of 'Object', I don't think my wrapper class will be so useful

Comment: Ok, then explain here your goal. What do want to do with wrapper class?

Comment: So your wrapper isn't a wrapper but a factory.

Comment: @Alvin if you want to access a method without creating object then you should make it `static` or `class` type. like: `public static func getNumber() -> Int`

Comment: Hi guys, the question has been updated. I am still learning generic in swift. Your guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: @Alvin How did you get your object model class? Do you even get the instances of these classes?

Answer (score 0):

How about this , in your example changing the type of wrapped from non-optional to an optional variable type.

```
 class Wrapper {

    let message = "Hello World"
    var wrapped : T?

    public func getData() -> T? {
        return wrapped
    }

}

class Object {

    let number = 100
    public func getNumber() -> Int {
        return number
    }
}

class SecondObject {

    let name = "Second Object"
    public func getName() -> String {
        return name
    }
}
```

and then using it as below

```
let example = Wrapper()
example.wrapped = Object()
let result1 = example.getData()?.getNumber() // ()
secondExample.wrapped = SecondObject()
let result2 = secondExample.getData()?.getName() 

if let val1 = result1 , let val2 = result2 {
    print("result1 = \(val1) result2 = \(val2)" )     
}
```